# I reached 200 reputation on puzzling, and received the association bonus on that site. Why?

Tags: bug, reputation

When I reached the two hundred reputation (on puzzling) required to get the association bonus, I received it on chess, stackoverflow, and arquade like I expected. Unlike I expected, **I also got it here**.

This doesn't seem quite right. The association bonus is to help established users on some sites get a leg up on other stackexchange sites, which makes sense - and I'm glad I got it on the other sites. Getting the bonus here just seems like a fairly pointless bonus for reaching 200 rep.

I like having the extra 100 reputation, but I don't think that I deserve it.

Edit: I just checked, and the rep bonus did not trigger 200 rep on another site.

Comment: That does sound like a bug. Is it possible that the bonus on one of those _other_ sites took your rep on that site past the magic 200 threshold, and then _that_ triggered the association bonus here on Puzzling?

Comment: No. My highest rep elsewhere is 176 on chess.

Comment: Because it would be weird to only boost all other pages. Imagine you have 101 rep. on one site and get 200 on another. Suddenly it would be 202 and 200 and your top account would be something different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's by design. You will get the association bonus on *all* sites.

From the help center, [What is reputation? How do I earn (and lose) it?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation)

> #### How do I earn reputation?
>
> [...]
>
> **You gain reputation when:**
>
> - [...]
> - site association bonus: +100 on **each** site (awarded a maximum of one time per site)
>
> If you are an experienced Stack Exchange network user with 200 or more reputation on at least one site, you will receive a starting +100 reputation bonus to get you past basic new user restrictions. **This will happen automatically on *all* current Stack Exchange sites where you have an account**, and on any other Stack Exchange sites at the time you log in.
>
> <sup>(Emphasis mine)</sup>

The help center doesn't say anything like "(excluding any sites where you already have 200 reputations)" at all.